# Solving $ y' = \alpha \exp(-y^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve the following differential equation

$$ y' = \alpha e^{-y^2} $$

How should I proceed ?

Comment: It's fairly well known that $\int e^{-x^2}$ can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_differential_equations#Separable_first-order_ordinary_differential_equations

Comment: $y$ is the unknown function. I did not write $e^{-x^2}$. Edit : My bad I wrote ODE, which was confusing. I edited the post.

Comment: Just note that $dx/dy = \alpha^{-1}e^{y^2}$.

Comment: You mean that I should find $y^{-1}$ and invert the result to get $y$ ? So as expected a non-closed formula... $y(x) = (\int_{y_0}^. \exp(u^2)du)^{-1}(x)$. Is that it ?

Comment: Use separation of variables, and then you have to find $\int e^{y^2}\,dy$, which can't be done using elementary functions.

Comment: To clarify, the ODE is separable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the differential equation as x is a function in y. This gives the answer:

$$ x={\frac {1/2\,i\sqrt {\pi }\,{{\rm erf}\left(iy\right)}}{\alpha}} + C $$.